# Increase spacing between cvcomputer & cvdoubleitem

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I want to write my CV with LaTeX and the `moderncv` package. My problem is that I use pretty long words in `\cvcomputer` and `\cvdoubleitem` and they overlay. For example,

```
\cvcomputer{thisisareallylongwordwhichwilloverlay}{Thatsright}{}{}
```

So I want to increase the spacing between the elements to give the words enough space to be fully displayed.

EDIT: Got the answer now, try this:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=20mm,right=20mm, top=1cm, bottom=2cm}
```

All credits go to [Lumpi](http://be-jo.net/2012/05/lebenslauf-mit-latex-mustervorlage/).